# What is the Famicom "Pulse Line" of games? How many games are part of this line?

Tags: nintendo, nes

<sub>(This question was inspired by [Did all NES "Black Box" games come in carts with five screws?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2170/621))</sub>

I've heard of the Famicom "Pulse Line" of games released in Japan shortly after the launch of the Family Computer.  Is there anything special about these games?  Is there a North American equivalent of this line?  How may "Pulse Line" games were released?

Comment: Related on meta: [Should the Famicom and NES tags be synonyms?](http://meta.retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/402/621)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just after the release of the Famicom in Japan, Nintendo released a collection of games with the same label design known informally as the "Pulse Line" of games.  One could deduce that Nintendo believed the best marketing strategy for new games was to keep the game label design consistent across multiple titles.  Later, Nintendo would create custom artwork for the labels on their cartridges.

[image: Pulse Line Carts]
<sub>[Image courtesy of /u/IsForInglip on /r/gamecollecting.](https://www.reddit.com/r/gamecollecting/comments/5shu7m/i_now_own_all_14_nintendo_pulse_line_famicom_carts/)</sub>

Some cases:

[image: Game Cases]

These carts have a label showing the title of the game in Japanese (Chinese for Taiwanese or Hong Kong releases) and English.  This line is equivalent to the North American "Black Box" line.  Additional information about "Black Box" games can be found in this question: [Did all NES "Black Box" games come in carts with five screws?](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/q/2170/621)

The 14 "Pulse Line" titles in order of release are:

- Donkey Kong
- Donkey Kong Jr.
- Popeye
- Gomokunarabe
- Mah-Jong
- Mario Bros.
- Popeye
- Baseball
- Donkey Kong Jr. Math
- Tennis
- Pinball
- Golf
- Donkey Kong 3
- Devil World